# Java keeps saying it can't find the jdbc mysql driver

Tags: mysql, jdbc, ubuntu-12.04, java

Here's yet another question about jdbc's mysql driver. Considering the number of search results I got when I googled, I'm pretty bummed nothing I found in them worked for me.

The error:

```
hostname# java -cp /usr/share/java/mysql-connector.jar:/home/user JDBCTest
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://<db ip>:3306/dbname
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
 at JDBCTest.main(sqltest.java:14)
```

The code (pulled from a short how to):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

class JDBCTest {

    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://dbipaddress:3306/dbname";

    private static final String user = "username";

    private static final String password = "password";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Success");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm 90% certain /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar is the correct path for the class. That's what I've found both online, and using locate.

I've tried setting the environment classpath to `CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar` in /etc/environment. As you can see, I've tried the -cp flag as well.

I can connect to the mysql server and database with the credentials I have in the JDBCTest class using the command line mysql-client. So it is not an error with the db server or my user/password.

As far as I can tell, my jdbc url is correct. That was one of the more common problems I found when searching...

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on my servers.

libmysql-java is installed. As is, openjdk-7-jre-headless.

I'm running this completely outside of Tomcat, so all the answers saying to copy the driver  into Tomcat's directory shouldn't apply.

So, I'm stumped. I would think using the -cp flag would just force it to work. Is there something in my java install missing? Something that got left out of openjdk-7-jre-headless?

How do I fix this?

Note: This class is just a quick test to help me diagnose why a larger (proprietary) app will not connect to my db. The larger app throws the same error. I'm hoping that fixing this small class will fix the larger app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using a version of the MySQL JDBC driver that is not JDBC 4 compliant, so it is not automatically loaded by `DriverManager`. In that case you need to explicitly load it using:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

The other option is to use a version of the library that is JDBC 4 compliant and will be automatically loaded.

Comment: I was on: mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar When I downloaded and used mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar, everything worked fine. Does that mean it was the JDBC 4 compliance issue?

Comment: @DavidR. Probably, interestingly enough, according to the [MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/en/news-5-1-16.html), 5.1.16 was never released.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following on the first line of your main method:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

If it throws an exception, then the JVM cannot access `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector.jar`. If that is the case, then check file permissions using:

```
ls -lah /usr/share/java/mysql-connector.jar
```

You should have at least read access to this file, and obviously the file should exist.

Comment: Um, that errors when I'm compiling. Which is done on my local Ubuntu 12.04 desktop, not the server. 

As for file perms, it errors when I run javac under sudo, and as my normal user. On the server, I'm running everything as root. The .jars are 644, and owned/grouped by root.