# Eclipse can't reach mysql connector driver in the project path

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, driver

I've been trying to create an eclipse JPA project but for some reason i get the following error.
[image: Driver error]

I created a a simple java project and dropped the libraries in a folder called lib, and added these jar files in the java build path:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/ci?useSSL=false
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.practico2.test.TestJDBC.main(TestJDBC.java:17)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java keeps saying it can't find the jdbc mysql driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943209/java-keeps-saying-it-cant-find-the-jdbc-mysql-driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `:` after the `mysql` in `jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/ci?useSSL=false`. It should be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ci?useSSL=false`.

Comment: This solved it, thanks, i was going crazy over the wrong thing.